# Test with selenium chrome driver is not loading the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I'm using **selenium-java** version: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.8.1, chrome driver version: ChromeDriver 2.29.461571, google chrome version: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).

When I'm running my tests, sometime google chrome is opening with the URL, not it is not sending the request to server it is waiting since a long time (not even closing or throwing error) and if I refresh the page or press enter on the address bar, it is loading the page.

Any idea, why it is happening and how can I fix this.

I have tried with org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver and org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver both, I'm facing the same problem.

**Just to add** - I'm using org.openqa.selenium.Proxy to set some http-headers.

Code:

```
Class Test {
    private static BrowserMobProxyServer proxyServer;
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            proxyServer = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
            proxyServer.start(0);
            Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxyServer);
            seleniumProxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.merge(capabilities);
            chromeOptions.setProxy(seleniumProxy);

            if (System.getProperties().containsKey("useRemoteWebDriver")) {
                RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                        new URL("http://localhost:4141/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
                remoteDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
                driver = remoteDriver;
            } else {
                ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("<driver path>"))
                        .usingAnyFreePort()
                        .build();
                driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            proxyServer.addHeader("H1", "Value1");

            driver.get("http://www.myURL.com/testApp");
    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading both Chrome and Chromedriver to latest versions.

Comment: DebanjanB - code added.

Comment: @Corey - upgraded both. Still facing the same problem.

Comment: Hello All, could you please help me here.

Comment: Investigated more and found that server is sending the response but selenium is not able to render the page and it is showing as "waiting for <server dns>"